# Additionally password protect an ASP.NET Core MVC website hosted as Azure WebApp with existing authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing ASP.NET Core MVC application with ASP.NET Core Identity where I use a combination of `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` and `[Authorize]` attributes to enforce that a user is logged in to website, has a certain role et cetera. This works fine locally and in an Azure WebApp.

Now, I want to publish a preview version of my application to another Azure WebApp. This time, I want each visitor to enter another set of credentials *before* anything from the website is being shown. I guess I'd like to have something like an .htaccess / BasicAuthenication equivalent. However, after a user entered the first set of credentials, he should not be logged in since he should need to use the normal login prodecure (just as in the live version which is publicly accessible but this has certain pages which require the user to be logged in). Basically, I just want to add another layer of password protection on top **without impacting the currently existing authentication**.

Given that I want allow access to anyone with the preview password, the following solutions do not seem to work in my case:

- Limit the access to the WebApp as a firewall setting. The client IPs will not be from a certain IP range and they will be dynamically assigned by their ISP.
- Use an individual user account with Azure AD in front. This might be my fallback (although I'm not sure on how to implement exactly) but I'd rather not have another set of *individual* user credentials to take care. The credentials could even be something as simple as preview // preview.

Is there a simple way like adding two lines of codes in the Startup class to achieve my desired second level of password protection?

Comment: .NetCore, have you considered deploying to a linux webapp... then you can have your htaccess login.

Comment: Currently, my multiple personal projects are still running on a Windows App Service Plan for historical reasons. I guess that changing the App Service Plan would be a solution, but that would require me to migrate each of the WebApps. I also have some WebJobs with Windows Executables running in the same Service Plan, so using a Linux WebApp would most likely require me to create a second App Service Plan which results in another ~30€ / month. I hope that I can find a solution that does not require money, but yeah, Linux WebApps might work

Comment: That makes sense. Also webjobs on a linux service plan is a problem. You'd end up having to write Azure Functions as a replacement for the webjobs. Not sure if there is a direct comparable feature for htaccess' login credentials.

Comment: @citronas this second layer of password protection you want, is it always going to be a static passoword ie: anyone that enters username: xxxxxxx and password: yyyyyy on top of their existing login will be allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a second auth via a basic auth, something simple and not too much code. You will need a middleware that will intercept/called after the original authentication is done

**Middleware**

```
public class SecondaryBasicAuthenticationMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    //CHANGE THIS TO SOMETHING STRONGER SO BRUTE FORCE ATTEMPTS CAN BE AVOIDED
    private const string UserName = "TestUser1";
    private const string Password = "TestPassword1";

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        //Only do the secondary auth if the user is already authenticated
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
            {
                // Get the encoded username and password
                var encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Split(' ', 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]?.Trim();

                // Decode from Base64 to string
                var decodedUsernamePassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));

                // Split username and password
                var username = decodedUsernamePassword.Split(':', 2)[0];
                var password = decodedUsernamePassword.Split(':', 2)[1];

                // Check if login is correct
                if (IsAuthorized(username, password))
                {                   
                    
                    await next.Invoke(context);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Return authentication type (causes browser to show login dialog)
            context.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic";

            // Return unauthorized
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        else
        {
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    //If you have a db another source you want to check then you can do that here
    private bool IsAuthorized(string username, string password) =>
        UserName == username && Password == password;
}
```

**In startup -> Configure (make sure you add this after your existing authentication and authorization)**

```
    //Enable Swagger and SwaggerUI
    app.UseMiddleware<SecondaryBasicAuthenticationMiddleware>(); //can turn this into an extension if you wish

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

**In Startup -> ConfigureServices register the middleware**

```
services.AddTransient<SecondaryBasicAuthenticationMiddleware>();
```

**And chrome should pop up a basic auth dialog like this**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, I want to do it in other order: Prompt for basic authentication first (and somehow cache that basic auth was success or send it on every request) and afterwards I have [AllowAnonymous] and [Authorize] pages. For the latter, I still need my normal authentication to work. I'm trying to invert your logic but I somehow haven't quite figured that out yet ;)

Comment: I can't seem to find out on how to invert the logic and somehow it won't prompt me either on the Basic Authentication. Might have something to do which me intercepting errors. Would you mind updating your example to always (unless cached successful validation) prompt for basic authentication and afterwards checking with the normal [AllowAnonymous] and [Authorize] pages? That would help me a lot ;)

Comment: Ok I have updated, I think if you want to run this custom auth first then you need to change to if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  then this will kick in for non authenticated users and only if you this is successful then you get to go through your existing authpipeline.

Comment: Thanks! When I disable `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`, your updated code will work perfectly. I still need to figure out how to exclude my error handling for 401 upon basic authentication call, but I hope that I will manage that somehow ;)